Can Office JavaScript API (Office JS) can be used outside of Office clients?
I am developing an independent application based on NodeJS and typescript which works on PowerPoint (read slides, metadata etc. ). I am interested in knowing if I can use office JS to process PowerPoint files outside of add-ins in any web application as it requires office context? I couldn’t find any documentation to support this. If not, what is best way to work with PowerPoint files to extract slide information in client-side application?
Looked into Microsoft docs

The Office JavaScript Library (aka Office.js) cannot initialize unless it is in the context of Office, so it cannot be used outside of an add-in.
If your scenario requires that your code be outside of an add-in, consider working at the level of the OOXML of the PowerPoint files: OOXML SDK.

Thank you Rick. OOXML is a server side library and based on .net. I am looking for something which I can use in NodeJs / JavaScript based client application.
